# IEnumerator not waiting for seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created an `IEnumerator` so that the enemy doesn't kill the player immediately on contact. the code worked fine yesterday, but now the `IEnumerator` seems to be completely ignored. The Unity 3d console is not showing any errors either.

I have tried to lower the damage amount to check if maybe it was too high but  it wasn't the case.

the following is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class enemyAI : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField]
  float chaseDistance = 5.0f;
  public float damageAmount = 1.0f;

  void Update () {
    dist = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
    if (distance < chaseDistance )
    {
      AttackPlayer();
    }
  }

  void AttackPlayer()
  {
    agent.updateRotation = false;
    Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    direction.y = 0;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
    agent.updatePosition = false;
    anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
    StartCoroutine(AttackTime());
  }

  IEnumerator AttackTime()
  {
    canAttack = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    Player.singleton.Damage(damageAmount);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    canAttack = true;
  }
}
```

```
//Player Script {
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
  public static Player singleton;
  public  float currentHealth;
  public static float maxHealth = 100f;
  public bool isDead = false;

  private void Awake()
  {
    singleton = this;
  }

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    if (currentHealth < 0)
    {
      currentHealth = 0;
    }
  }

  public void Damage(float damage)
  {
    if(currentHealth > 0)
    {
      currentHealth -= damage;
    }
    else
    {
      currentHealth = 0;
    }
  }

  void Dead()
  {
    currentHealth = 0;
    isDead = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Having AttackPlayer in update seems pointless to me. You shouldn't "attack the player" every frame AND wait multiple frames between attacks in the same logic sequence. --- Either set the parameters for *starting multiple attacks* in update, and let the whole repeating-attacks (and stop-attacking) logic inside the coroutine, or setup a delta-time stopwatch logic in update and don't use coroutines at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting the "AttackPlayer" Coroutine in "Update()" - so when the enemy is in range, you will start ~60 Coroutines per second. While you want a single one.

You are already setting "canAttack" to "false" - maybe add "&& canAttack" to your range-condition in Update?

Like

```
    if (distance < chaseDistance && canAttack)
    {

        AttackPlayer();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "canAttack = false;" beneath yield command